# Get the angle from a rotated matrix using glm?

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, angle, glm-math

I want to know how to get the angle from a rotated matrix, how do I calculate that? I am using glm c++.

For example
how do I get the angle from this matrix using c++?

```
[-0.01458][-2.26652][0][0]
[-1.27492][-0.02596][0][0]
[    0   ][    0   ][1][0]
[    x   ][    y   ][z][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an identity matrix that was rotated around Z axis. If that's always the case, you can get the angle back by applying [glm::atan](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00136.html#ga5db83034488156692939acb4f4e46fa6) function on the first two elements of the first column:

```
float get_angle_in_rad(const glm::mat4 &matrix) {
    return glm::atan(matrix[0][1], matrix[0][0]);
}
```

See [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for explanation.

Note that if the matrix represents more complicated tranformation than just rotation around Z axis, the value returned by this function will be bogus. Depending on your usecase you may want to keep the euler rotation angles separately, in addition to the transformation matrix.